# I want to learn security testing

Tags: security

I want to learn security testing. The most important security testing types are : sql injection attacks, cross-site scripting, phishing attack. I don't know how to start learning. I want to find some tutorial or can anyone please explain to me how to start ? Are there any tools available ?

Comment: Security testing is a specialized domain: you will probably find more information and get better answers at http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Read the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) site.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.  This question is very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this really good list:
http://katrinatester.blogspot.de/2015/09/security-testing-pathway.html

And this free courses:
https://www.cybrary.it

Answer (score 3):

To start with, I'd suggest installing [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and exploring your website with it. There's plenty of information available about how to use Fiddler and it makes a decent starting point to explore and try to manipulate data going to your application. (I have no affiliation with Telerik - I just use the software as my first pass security tool).

Beyond that, I'd recommend searching for tutorials in the different types of security testing, as well as searching the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site for beginner-level information.

A few other pieces of general advice for you:

- If you/your employer doesn't control the software, don't try to learn security testing on it. Not every public site wants to have their security tested by anyone who feels like it.
- Try to learn on a test environment. It may not have everything locked down (e.g. many test environments don't use SSL), but the fundamentals of the application should be the same. More importantly, on a test environment, if you accidentally do something horrible to the server or database, you can recover. Doing that to your employer's live software could get you fired.
- Search engines are your friend.

Comment: I'll reiterate part of that advice: performing security testing on a public site without the owner's permission is almost indistinguishable from black hat hacking. In some countries, it can land you in jail.